# How would you interpret a low correlation coefficient and low p-value?

Tags: statistics

I have the following output and am unsure how to interpret the results. Obviously there is a strong correlation and it is statistically significant for Vacancy, but I'm confused on how to read the UPTO and LOAs outputs.

UPTO has a strong-ish correlation, but we're dealing with a high p-value...does this mean this relationship should be ignored? Vice Versa with LOAs.

The n-size I'm working with is 29 observations and I understand p-value is 'sensitive' to this, but I don't know to what degree in this example.

| Variable | Correlation | P-Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vacancy | .78 | .0028 |
| UPTO | .54 | .284 |
| LOAs | -.19 | .089 |

Comment: You don't explain what the analysis generated the results and what further analysis you are considering. The best advice may be to plot the data and that might help understand the results

Comment: Interesting question, but off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. You'll want to say more about the context around this problem, in order to help others help you.